# Do Carmo Differential Geometry: Maps are defined as sets

Tags: differential-geometry

In his book, Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces, Do Carmo defines curves to be maps, while he defines (regular) surfaces to be sets rather than maps.

Is there a particular reason he chose to define them this way? That is, why are curves *not* defined as sets, and vice versa? Must surfaces be defined as sets because  you cannot always construct a surface with one particular 'map' but rather, patch together multiple maps to cover the said surface in a smooth manner (and with no intersections)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also define curves as sets, but in the end you cannot escape using functions to describe a curve.

Here is a definition, mimicking the definition of surfaces:

A curve $C\subseteq\Bbb R^3$ is a subset of $\Bbb R^3$ satisfying the following property:

For every point $p\in C$ there exists an open neighbourhood $U\subseteq\Bbb R^3$ of $p$, an open set $V\subseteq\Bbb R$, and a smooth function $f:V\to U$ such that

1. $f:V\to U\cap C$ is a homeomorphism.
2. For each $t\in V$, the derivative $f'(t)$ is not the zero vector.

As you can see, the function $f$ would essentially be the function that defines the curve.

You can define parametric surfaces like how you define parametric curves. You can say that a parametric surface is a smooth function $f:V\to\Bbb R^3$ from an open set $V\subseteq\Bbb R^2$. If the Jacobian matrix of $f$ is injective everywhere in the domain $V$, $f$ is said to be regular. This definition appears on page 80 of do Carmo's Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces, second edition.

Comment: Found it! Thanks